# Check kubelet startup options/settings?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Kubernetes kubelets can be run with a specific set of options (https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/). Is there a way to see, through kubectl or similar way, the options that kubelet was run with?

I basically want to know if `--allow-privileged` was passed in, but see no way of checking that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ps x | grep kubelet` or `cat /proc/$(pidof kubelet)/cmdline` to get commandline.

If kubelet is installed by `apt` or `yum`, mostly it's working as a systemd service.

Take a look at files in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/` folder, where the arguments kubelet running with.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this would work

```
systemctl status kubelet | less
```